# Find nearest boundary of inner feature (Turf.js)

Tags: boundaries, turf

Imagine a GeoJSON FeatureCollection that contains a boundary and a feature.

The feature should be thought of as a Building and the boundary as a plot of land.

When rendered this shows the follow https://gist.github.com/ciarans/de4d049bbc3bbe38c82988885d3451a3

```json
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              2.3407745361328125,
              48.14272340433032
            ],
            [
              2.2254180908203125,
              48.14134883691423
            ],
            [
              2.2473907470703125,
              48.1078896843694
            ],
            [
              2.243270874023437,
              48.01059706170417
            ],
            [
              2.3263549804687496,
              47.99359789867388
            ],
            [
              2.394332885742187,
              47.94026691125948
            ],
            [
              2.360687255859375,
              47.898851481269304
            ],
            [
              2.5419616699218746,
              47.89332691887659
            ],
            [
              2.489089965820312,
              47.92968612174219
            ],
            [
              2.4884033203125,
              48.04641478400926
            ],
            [
              2.3407745361328125,
              48.14272340433032
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              2.449951171875,
              48.06201984745272
            ],
            [
              2.404632568359375,
              48.08587726774227
            ],
            [
              2.373046875,
              48.07394994028581
            ],
            [
              2.41973876953125,
              48.050545996347665
            ],
            [
              2.449951171875,
              48.06201984745272
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

I am trying to find a solution that will return the minimum and maximum distance for each "side" of the "Building" to the relative boundary.

Here is what I am doing so far;

1. Take a Polygon within the Boundary
2. Convert it to a minimum bounding rectangle (using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/geojson-minimum-bounding-rectangle)

I am now stuck on how to calculate the distance of each side to the boundary.

In my mind, I want to take two corners of a side of the polygon and grow it till it hits the boundary.

Comment: Its possible but first you need to make sure the question is precisely defined. You want the lengths of those arrows from your diagram? How are they defined? Are they meant to be at right angles to the sides of the building from where they come from? Do they start at the midpoint of the side? Its not "the minimum distance for each side to the boundary" since there are points on the boundary that are a *lot* closer to each side. Please try and make a precise definition of your problem.

Comment: Thank you I've amended my question

Comment: What do you mean by "grow it"? In what direction? Is your inner polygon always parallelogram?  And please don't explain how would you try to do it with turf.js, but rather describe the principle as you would do it by hand (paper, pencil).